# Replacing a switch with MOSFETs

Tags: transistors, mosfet, switches

I currently have a 2:1 switch / multiplexer which is being used to switch between two different batteries which are to provide power to a small module on my board. The switch that I am using is the [TS5A3154](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ts5a3154.pdf) and I am wanting to switch between the channels using  an output pin from my microcontroller (EFM32G222F128).

The issue that I am having is that the battery voltage is going to be approx. 2.7 - 3V which will be at both of the analogue inputs (NC and NO) and the supply voltage for this switch is going to be only 2.5 - 2.8V - due to V+ coming from a dual schottky diode which draws the current equally from each battery and also prevents on discharging through the other in the event of a battery failure so this part is needed.

Because of this small difference between the analogue inputs and V+, the Enable pin does not function properly (ie. when there is a high signal at the pin there is a high output when it should actually be off completely) and because of this I need to replace the switch with either a new component or a new solution which would only have a small voltage drop across it or be very low resistance.

I have already had a look around for alternative switches or multiplexers but it appears to me that the same problem would always be present for any alternatives that I looked at.

Low cost is also fairly important but at the moment I am more interested in any solution as opposed to a low cost one. The solution would also need to have a similar Enable function the current switch has in that the power to the module can be cut off at some point - either just by turning two separate things off or having one switch that would do it.

A schematic of what it currently is shown below might be of help for understanding a little more:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why not use two devices then each can be powered by their individual local battery supply.

If not then TI have a range of power/load switches that may be suitable. I'm thinking of the TPS2080 listed on [this](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/power-management/power-mux-current-limited-switch-products.page#o7=Current-Limited%20Load%20Switch&p480=2;2) page amongst other devices that may also be suitable. The TPS2080 is a dual supply with <0.1 ohms on resistance and supports a change over contact. It has a built-in charge pump that should overcome the problem you have.

If all else fails then create a low power "higher" voltage rail and use this for the chip supply.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be worth placing a diode in line with the NO and NC pin connections to drop the voltage from the batteries to nearer or slightly below the common V+ value ?

Are you sure the problem is not that the control signals are higher then V+ ?  A simple resistor voltage divider on the signal pins could solve that.

Comment: If you have any continuous pulses in the system you might use that to create a small charge-pump input to the V+ pin.  A small cap on the V+ pin will help store the charge.

Comment: It can't really afford to have a diode drop as the module it will be powering needs to be on for as long as possible and a drop in voltage would already reduce that time significantly.  And it wouldn't be constantly pulsing - only every now and again